# regex.ismatch is never matching

Tags: regex

i'm trying to verify if a string matches with the following pattern "12:24:35", and this is the code that i'm using to do it:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textbox_TiempoDePrueba.Text, @"^[0-9]{2}\:\[0-9]{2}\:\[0-9]{2}$"))
{
//do something if there's not match
}
```

The thing is, when textbox_TiempoDePrueba.Text is "00:00:10", there's not match.
I'm new using Regex.IsMatch and I don´t know what is wrong with my code since i never get a match.

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I think it's C#

Comment: You're checking if the regex doesn't match with `!`, is that you really want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're regex looks fine expect for the escaping brackets, change `\[` to `[`,
also,  you're checking if the **regex doesn't match** with `!`, is that what you really want ?

If you don't need to validate the time first, you can use:

```
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(textbox_TiempoDePrueba.Text, @"^[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}$")) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

---

Regex Explanation:

```
^[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}$

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character that is a “digit” «[\d]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “:” literally «:»
Match a single character that is a “digit” «[\d]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “:” literally «:»
Match a single character that is a “digit” «[\d]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any «$»
```

Answer (score 2):

You are escaping the `[` brackets in you pattern. Remove it; and the pattern should work:

```
if ( !Regex.IsMatch(textbox_TiempoDePrueba.Text, @"^[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}$") )
```

And an alternative pattern would be:

```
if ( !Regex.IsMatch(textbox_TiempoDePrueba.Text, @"^([0-9]{2}\:){2}[0-9]{2}$") )
```